# How long until a beginner group from several races can meet in World Of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Three friends and I want to try out the World Of Warcraft-Starter Edition this weekend (One will get an account in order to be able to form a group). We're all beginners with little or no experience in World Of Warcraft.

Of course we'll play on the same realm and on the same side, but not everyone will play the same race. I was wondering how long we'll have to spend time apart in the beginning, until we all can meet up and go question together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an easy way to play together right from the get-go.

Whoever gets the full account uses **Recruit-a-friend** to invite all of the other players to create their trial accounts.

Once you are in the game, the "veteran" account will be able to **summon all of the recruits directly to him**.  While it may feel a little strange to be an Undead in the Tauren starting zone, you will have access to all the same quests (except class-specific ones).

And now with the advent of automatically learned skills, you don't even need to worry about not having a trainer nearby!

There is one *potential* drawback: Recruit-a-friend gives you all a 300% experience boost. You will gain levels very quickly, and as new players you may find the learning curve a bit steep.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on race.

Goblin/Worgan/Pandarian forces you to play through there starting zones, you cant leave until you have completed the starting zones, not even to join a battleground that would send you back to the place you entered it when it was finished.

For all other races you can run to other starting zones after creating your character but the trip would be long on foot, completing the first starting zone would put you at level 5+ and also make questing together easier since if i recall correct there is race limitations on the intro quests(level 1-5).

Orc/Troll and Dwarf/Gnome start together.

All races have transportation between capital city and once you reach level 10 you can also sign up for Battle grounds and at level 15 you can sign up for dungeons

Comment: It's been a while since I played Alliance, is there still a transport issue between Darnassus and Stormwind/Ironforge? If so, watch out Night Elves, it's a long walk from Wetlands to Ironforge :)

Comment: @Flater if i recall correct theres a boat between stormwind and darnassus since the intruduction of stormwind harbor

Comment: Well that would solve the problem. The problem of me not knowing that is just because I'm so hardcore Horde ;-)

Comment: Yeah you have Darn -> SW and then you can SW -> IF

Answer (score 2):

Level 5 or 6 to finish up the starter area would be a good time to consider this.  You might have an interesting run, but I believe travel for newer players between capitals has become much easier in Cataclysm.  At level 5-6 a player has finished the tutorial area and is ready to move on to normal questing.

Comment: Every race's starting area is divided into a 1-5 area and the rest of the zone (which is 5-10). Either of these levels (5 or 10) is a good time to break out and meet up.